# Java Mysql Create Table with two Foreign key errno: 150 "Foreign key constraint is incorrectly formed

Tags: java, mysql, foreign-keys

I'm trying to create a table with two foreign keys, It worked when I created one, but now It crash...

I started few time ago with SQL.. Maybe It's a noob problem, I searched the  error trying to solve It, but I didn't find the answer.

It returns "Can't create table `base_de_datos_java`.`puntfinal` (errno: 150 "Foreign key constraint is incorrectly formed")"

```
import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.DriverManager;
import java.sql.PreparedStatement;
import java.sql.ResultSet;
import java.sql.SQLException;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Equipo {
static Connection conexion;

public static void main(String[] args) {
    try {
        Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
        conexion = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost/base_de_datos_java", "root", "");
    } catch (SQLException e) {
        System.out.println(e.getMessage());
        // e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        System.out.println(e.getMessage());
        // e.printStackTrace();
    }
    Equipo e = new Equipo();
    String sentenciaSQLCrearTablaEquipo = "CREATE TABLE Equipo(Nombre_Equipo VARCHAR(30),ID_Equipo INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT ,PRIMARY KEY (ID_Equipo));";
    String sentenciaSQLCrearTablaPuntuacion = "CREATE TABLE Puntuacion(ID_Equipo INT ,Puntuacion_Partido INT, CONSTRAINT FK_ID_EquipoPuntuacion FOREIGN KEY (ID_Equipo) REFERENCES Equipo(ID_Equipo));";
    String sentenciaSQLCrearTablaPuntFinal = "CREATE TABLE PuntFinal(Nombre_Equipo VARCHAR(30), ID_Equipo INT, Puntuacion_Total INT, CONSTRAINT FK_ID_EquipoPuntFinal FOREIGN KEY (ID_Equipo) REFERENCES Equipo (ID_Equipo), CONSTRAINT FK_Nombre_Equipo FOREIGN KEY (Nombre_Equipo) REFERENCES Equipo (Nombre_Equipo));";
    String sentenciaSQLRemoverTablaEquipo = "DROP TABLE IF EXISTS Puntuacion,PuntFinal,Equipo;";
    System.out.println("Iniciando... \nRemoviendo tablas anteriores...");
    e.Conexion(sentenciaSQLRemoverTablaEquipo);
    System.out.println("1º Creando tabla Equipo");
    e.Conexion(sentenciaSQLCrearTablaEquipo);
    System.out.println("2º Creando tabla Puntiacion");
    e.Conexion(sentenciaSQLCrearTablaPuntuacion);
    System.out.println("3º Creando tabla Puntuacion final");
    e.Conexion(sentenciaSQLCrearTablaPuntFinal);
    System.out.println("4º Creacion de las tablas correctamente");

    String sentenciaSQLInsertarDatosEquipo = "INSERT INTO Equipo (Nombre_Equipo) VALUES('Barça')";
    String sentenciaSQLInsertarDatosPuntuacion = "INSERT INTO Puntuacion VALUES(1,90)";
    String sentenciaSQLInsertarDatosPuntFinal = "INSERT INTO PuntFinal VALUES()";
    System.out.println("Insertando datos en la tabla Equipo");
    e.Conexion(sentenciaSQLInsertarDatosEquipo);

}

public void Conexion(String sentencia) {
    try {
        PreparedStatement st = (PreparedStatement) conexion.prepareStatement(sentencia);
        st.execute();
    } catch (SQLException e) {
        System.out.println(e.getMessage());
        // e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        System.out.println(e.getMessage());
        // e.printStackTrace();
    }

}
}
```

I add a better view of SQL sentences:

```
CREATE TABLE PuntFinal(
Nombre_Equipo VARCHAR(30),
ID_Equipo INT,
Puntuacion_Total INT,
CONSTRAINT FK_ID_EquipoPuntFinal FOREIGN KEY (ID_Equipo) REFERENCES Equipo (ID_Equipo),
CONSTRAINT FK_Nombre_Equipo FOREIGN KEY (Nombre_Equipo) REFERENCES Equipo (Nombre_Equipo)
 );

CREATE TABLE Puntuacion(
ID_Equipo INT ,
Puntuacion_Partido INT,
CONSTRAINT FK_ID_EquipoPuntuacion FOREIGN KEY (ID_Equipo) REFERENCES Equipo(ID_Equipo)
);

CREATE TABLE Equipo(
Nombre_Equipo VARCHAR(30),
ID_Equipo INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
PRIMARY KEY (ID_Equipo));
```

Comment: in which line you get the error?

Comment: I modified adding the error.

Comment: Guess it's a case of a missing comma, try putting it before `FOREIGN KEY (ID_Equipo) REFERENCES Equipo (ID_Equipo)` in your  sentenciaSQLCrearTablaPuntFinal

Comment: @coolgirl do you mean like this? `,CONSTRAINT FK_ID_EquipoPuntFinal ,FOREIGN KEY (ID_Equipo) REFERENCES Equipo (ID_Equipo),` This code don't not work, It returns You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near 'FOREIGN KEY (ID_Equipo) REFERENCES Equipo (ID_Equipo),CONSTRAINT FK_Nombre_Equip' at line 1

Comment: Mybad! That was wrong. You are referring `Nombre_Equipo` as  FK in your `PuntFinal` table, whereas it is not defined as a PK in `Equipo` table. Can  you verify plz? If you dont  want it to  be a FK try having a unique constraint on it.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is...
I can't make a FK of a non PK of the other table.

There was an issue on the statement of the exercise :S.